# Command 'expo' not found, node installed with NVM

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, yarnpkg, nvm

I am in Xubuntu 18.04. I have installed my node with NVM.

```
$ nvm ls
       v10.20.1
->     v12.16.3
         system
default -> 12.16.3 (-> v12.16.3)
```

My default node version is 12.16.3. **I can not install expo with npm**. It shows some error

```
$ npm install expo-cli --global
```

**Then I tried to install expo with yarn** -

```
$ yarn global add expo

success Installed "expo@37.0.12" with binaries:
      - expo
      - expo-cli
Done in 71.61s.
```

I have checked the node installation directory -

```
$ npm config get prefix
/home/shahjalal/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3
```

But in `/home/shahjalal/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/bin/` directory I have only

```
$ ls
create-react-app  node  npm  npx
```

No expo inside the `/home/shahjalal/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/bin/` directory

So, I am getting -

**Command 'expo' not found**

How can I get the expo client.